# Embed .WMV files in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, embed, wmv

I had a solution to show both `.MP4` and `.WMV` embedded in the browser. It worked fine in both IE and Chrome, but for some time ago it stopped working in Chrome. Chrome will not show any files (`mp4` or `wmv`), but it works fine in IE. I googled it, and found several reasons to why Chromes newer version couldn't deal with this, but no solution to my problem.

The solution that worked was `<object><embed>`, but this only works in IE now. Then I tried to add the `<video>` tag and got it to work with `mp4` in Chrome, but not with `wmv`.

So, is it anyone that have a solution to embed a wmv file that will run without problems in Chrome?

The requirements is that it should be able to play both `MP4` and `WMV` files in Chrome and IE.

Comment: why not using video.js or alternative solutions and using mp4, ogv and webm? works in all browsers. please also define which ie versions you need.

Answer (score 0):

The long and short of it is that there is no solution. The `<video>` tag is supported by [almost all browsers](http://caniuse.com/video) now, but there are different levels of support for different formats:

- MP4 - [Good support](http://caniuse.com/mpeg4) (noone uses Opera anyway). Works with both the browsers you mentioned.
- WebM - [Patchy support](http://caniuse.com/webm), definitely none on IE for the time being
- WMV - I can't even find anyone giving a hard answer on this one, but I think the general concensus is that `<video>` is the way to go, and that to use one of the two above formats is the way to go. MP4 seems the better choice for the time being. If there are requirements to say that you must achieve the impossible/pointless, I'd suggest that your requirements-setters familiarise themselves with ffmpeg :)